# Custom fields for test reporting in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I would like to have additional fields in Jenkins that would be useful for reporting, for instance team names assigned to the automated tests, so that each team can clearly see their own tests.

Is it possible to add new custom fields to Jenkins reports and if so how can the field values be filled?

**edit:** Cut question down to make it more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no answers for this that do not involve nasty workarounds.

Instead, I will a [feature request](http://jenkins.361315.n4.nabble.com/Feature-Request-Custom-Fields-for-reporting-td4562008.html) was submitted to the Jenkins project.

*(updates here if and when the feature is released)*

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, and didn't find any straight forward solution. my workaround is to add it to std-out of the test, then it is possible to see it in jenkins later.